# What can a Mac do that a Windows machine can't?

Tags: macos, mac, windows

Can I have some definitive answers? Also, what are you forced to do on a Windows machine that is not required on a Mac?

Comment: This question is too subjective for this site. Voting to close. Please see the [faq] for more information.

Comment: Answer: be asked about on this SE site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Mac is licensed to run some Apple software that is not licensed to run on non-Mac hardware.  Other than that, they are both Turing-complete computational engines that can emulate any other computational engine given enough time and memory.

Answer (score 2):

It can be taken to the Genius Bar at an Apple store for diagnosis and cure.

It entitles one to purchase AppleCare, which includes unlimited telephone support for the duration of the contract.

It can connect to Thunderbolt peripherals.

It can survive a user tripping over its power cord, because the power cord is held in place on the machine by a magnet rather than by friction.

It can legally run both Lion and Windows 7.